# How many angles are being formed in the attached image?

Tags: geometry, angle

Could anyone help me understand the answer of this question? This question is asked in 6th grade as part of the CBSE curriculum.

I think the answer should be $4$ due to $4$ right angles.
Should the $4$ straight angles $\angle AOB$, $\angle DOC$, $\angle BOA$, and $\angle COD$ and $4$ (full or complete) $360^{\circ}$ angles $\angle AOA$, $\angle DOD$, $\angle BOB$ and $ \angle COC$ be also considered?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Answer depends on angle definition. I believe one needs to exclude $\angle AOA$ but take into account $\angle AOB$. $\angle AOB$ is the same as $\angle BOA$, so one doesn't need to count it twice. Then answer is just ${4\choose 2}$.